# className null or not an object in IE8

Tags: jquery, css

I am running the below code in IE8 and I am getting className is null or not an object. Any help

**JS:**

```
var validators = {
    allowalphanum: function (val) {
        return /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(val);
    },
    allownospace: function (val) {
        return !/\s/.test(val);
    }
}

$('#submit_form .required').blur(function () {
    var returnVal1 = true;
    var classes = $(this).className.split(/\s+/);
    for (var p in classes) {
        if (classes[p] in validators) {
            returnVal1 = returnVal1 & validators[classes[p]](input.val());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You say this is broken in IE8, but `$(this).className` is just simply wrong, and shouldn't work in *any* browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your code:

```
var classes = $(this).className.split(/\s+/);
```

with this:

```
var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
```

Actually `className` is a DOM property. It's not a property of jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

Use either vanilla js:

```
var classes = this.className.split(/\s+/);
```

or use jQuery method attr:

```
var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var classes = $(this).className.split(/\s+/);
```

I don't recall `className` being a valid jQuery method. `.attr('class')` is probably what you need if you want to use the jQuery object.

Other answers has already been posted on how to do that without jQuery.

`$(this)` differs from `this` as the first one gives you a jQuery object, the second a DOM object.